# What is the meaning for the error "cant locate object method via package" in perl?

Tags: perl, oop

I have declared a base class `chocolatecake.pm` and a derived class `birthdaycake.pm` in Perl. The following error is shown.

Can anyone please explain what this error means?

#### chocolatecake.pm

```perl
 #!usr/bin/perl
    package chocolate_cake;
    sub new
    {
        $class=shift;
        $self={};
    bless($self,$class);
    return $self;
}

sub bake
{
    print "The cake is backing\n"
}
sub frose
{
    print "The cake is frosing\n";
}
sub put_handle_on

{
    $self=shift;
    $numOfCan=shift;
    print "The $numOfCan in chocalate cake\n";
}
1;
```

#### birthdaycake.pm

```perl
package birthday_cake;
@ISA = (chocalate_cake);
sub new
{
    $class=shift;
    $self={};
    bless($self,$class);
    return $self;
}
sub put_candles_on
{
    my $self=shift;
    my $numOfCan=shift;
    print "The $numOfCan in birthday cake\n";
}
1;
```

#### main.pl

```perl
use birthday_cake;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';

$cake_bi=new birthday_cake();
print blessed($cake_bi),"\n";
$cake_bi->bake();
```

I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Can't locate object method "bake" via package "birthday_cake"
> ```

Comment: How are the files named?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You should add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl source file you write
- You don't need a shebang line at the top of a module file because it is never normally run as a program
- You have misspelled as couple of things, such as `chocalate_cake` / `chocolate_cake` / `chocolatecake.pm` and `birthday_cake` / `birthdaycake.pm`
- It's important that your module file names should match their package names, and should start with a capital letter
- To write a subclass, you need to both `require` a base class and put its name into `@ISA`. `use parent 'BaseClass'` is a convenient way to do both of these things at once
- Your subclass should probably call the constructor of the base class with `SUPER::new` before adding any new fields that you need

This set of modules works fine. I have written `add_candles` to *add* a number of candles to the cake, and an accessor `candles` to discover how many candles it currently has

#### ChocolateCake.pm

```perl
package ChocolateCake;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    bless {}, $class;
}

sub bake {
    print "The cake is baking\n";
}

sub freeze {
    print "The cake is freezing\n";
}

1;
```

#### BirthdayCake.pm

```perl
package BirthdayCake;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use parent 'ChocolateCake';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);
    $self->{candles} = 0;

    $self;
}

sub add_candles {
    my $self = shift;
    my $num_candles = shift;
    $self->{candles} += $num_candles;

    print "The cake has $self->{candles} candles\n";
}

sub candles {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->{candles};
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use BirthdayCake;

my $cake = BirthdayCake->new;

$cake->bake;

$cake->add_candles(10);
$cake->add_candles(20);

printf "My cake is a %s with %d candles\n", ref $cake, $cake->candles;
```

#### output

```
The cake is baking
The cake has 10 candles
The cake has 30 candles
My cake is a BirthdayCake with 30 candles
```

Answer (score 7):

Two problems here:

- `chocalate_cake` and `chocolate_cake` are two different strings.
- your `birthday_cake.pm` is missing `use chocolate_cake`.

Also, it'll help you in the future if you get into the habit of using `strict` and `warnings` in all your scripts.

Writing `birthday_cake->new` is safer then the "indirect object syntax" you used (and if you're paranoic, you can use `'birthday_cake'->new` as I usually do, or even `birthday_cake::->new`, especially when you don't use Capitalized class names).